# How pass data from Controller to View?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new and below average student but I don't quite Here in this Codeigniter I'm facing data pass issue someone please help me out with a simple method.

**Controller**

```
public function View_data(){
      $this->load->model('student_model');
      $data["fetch_data"]=$this->student_model->view_student();
      $this->load->view(student_view,$data);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 
     echo $fetch_data;
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: what's the problem ?doesn't this work?

Comment: No giving error undefined variable error.

Answer (score 4):

Controller should be

```
$this->load->view('student_view',$data); # wrap view name with quotes
```

---

And **you're passing an array**. So you have to *loop it with `foreach`* or should *call through the index of the array*.

```
foreach ($fetch_data as $key => $item) {
    echo $item->element; # or  $item['element']
}
```

If using the index then

```
$fetch_data[0]['element']
```

> **Accesing method will ve various with how you get data in model**

Answer (score 1):

I think the view name `student_view` should be inside quotation marks.

From

```
$this->load->view(student_view,$data);
```

to

```
$this->load->view('student_view',$data);
```

which is probably the reason why `$data` is not passing to the view.

Answer (score 1):

on your **view** do like this

```
<?php 
    foreach($fetch_data as $fd) {
     echo $fd->name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 $this->load->view(student_view,['fetch_data' => $fetch_data]);


public function View_data(){
      $this->load->model('student_model');
      $fetch_data = $this->student_model->view_student();
      $this->load->view(student_view,['fetch_data' => $fetch_data]);
}

To check the data on view:

echo '<pre>'; print_r($fetch_data); echo '</pre>';
```

if you ate passing array form model then at the view you can try like this:

#### In Array

```
echo $fetch_data[0]['your_column']; //If there is multiple row 
echo $fetch_data['your_column']; //If there is single row
```

#### In stdClass Object

```
echo $fetch_data[0]->your_column; //If there is multiple row 
echo $fetch_data->your_column; //If there is single row
```